# Why does the submit button only work when pressed twice on my example?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, textinput

Please look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uNbYu/1/

When the submit button is pressed once, It removes the text edit for no apparent reason, but doesn't do anything, but the second time, it does work when pressed, and goes to the page.

Please help me with what makes this code do that.

Thanks

---

HTML:

```
<b class = "edit" id = "fooo"> FOO </b>
```

JS:

```
$('b.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().after('<form action = "foo.php" method = post><input hidden name = "field" type = "text" value = "' + this.id + '"/><input type="text" name = "period" class="editP" value="' + $(this).html() + '" /><input type = "submit" value = "Submit!!" /></form>');
    $('.editP').focus();
});
$('.editP').live('blur', function() {
    $(this).hide().prev('b.edit').html($(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the edit box loses focus before you manage to click the button thus changing the position so that you won't hit the button.

Comment: He is absolutely right. Try removing both cases of `.hide()` and it works.

Comment: @Marcus is there any way to preserve the `.hide()` yet maintain this?

Answer (score 4):

This is what your code says:

1. When text is clicked, create a new input element, submit button and form.
2. On blur hide the input element (not the submit button)

So when you click submit the first time it is actually firing the blur event and hiding the input.

Also, your old text is not being reshown because you use `.prev` to get it. This select previous adjacent sibling, but because the input element is in a form, the other element is not a sibling.

This Fiddle should make what is wrong more obvious. Note how the initial alert does not retrieve the text FOO. Also try and click submit button.

http://jsfiddle.net/uNbYu/8/

Answer (score 0):

1)  When you click the text, your code creates the form and put the focus on `.editP`.

```
$('.editP').focus();
```

2)  The rest of your code says to hide `.editP` when it loses focus (blur).

```
$('.editP').live('blur', function(){
    $(this).hide().prev('b.edit').html($(this).val()).show();
});
```

3)  So the act of *trying* to click the button causes the blur event to trigger on `editP`. This hides `.editP` thus shifting over the button which prevents it from being clicked.  It happens very fast... before you can actually successfully click the button.